# PPA Failed to fetch: the package it is looking for is out of date

Tags: apt, ppa

A PPA is giving apt upgrade errors because the update is trying to install a package which has been removed and replaced with a newer one.

```
apt dist-upgrade --fix-missing
```

is suggested as a fix, but it results in the same error.

I have been getting this error on a couple of machines for about 48 hours or so.

```
Failed to fetch https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/damentz/liquorix/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-liquorix/linux-headers-liquorix-amd64_6.2-4ubuntu1%7ejammy_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.52 443]


The package version "linux-headers-liquorix-amd64_6.2-4..." is no longer present in the PPA. It was replaced March 13 with 

    Package files
    
        linux-headers-6.2.6-1-liquorix-amd64_6.2-5ubuntu1~jammy_amd64.deb (12.4 MiB)
        linux-headers-liquorix-amd64_6.2-5ubuntu1~jammy_amd64.deb (170.6 KiB)
        linux-image-6.2.6-1-liquorix-amd64_6.2-5ubuntu1~jammy_amd64.deb (131.3 MiB)
        linux-image-liquorix-amd64_6.2-5ubuntu1~jammy_amd64.deb (170.6 KiB)
        linux-liquorix_6.2-5ubuntu1~jammy.debian.tar.xz (780.9 KiB)
        linux-liquorix_6.2-5ubuntu1~jammy.dsc (2.5 KiB)
        linux-liquorix_6.2.orig.tar.xz (130.1 MiB)
```

Why is it trying to install an older package?

There appears to be a version mismatch in the packaging.

I don't know much about `.debs` but I guess it is not good that the version string does not match the package.

This is from my 22.10 laptop:

```
/var/lib/apt/lists/ppa.launchpadcontent.net_damentz_liquorix_ubuntu_dists_kinetic_main_binary-amd64_Packages

    Package: linux-headers-6.2.5-4-liquorix-amd64
    Source: linux-liquorix
    Priority: optional
    Section: kernel
    Installed-Size: 97020
    Maintainer: Steven Barrett <steven@liquorix.net>
    Architecture: amd64
    Version: 6.2-4ubuntu1~kinetic
    Depends: libbabeltrace1 (>= 1.5.4~rc1), libc6 (>= 2.34), libcap2 (>= 1:2.10), libdw1 (>= 0.158), libelf1 (>= 0.144), liblzma5 (>= 5.1.1alpha+20120614), libnuma1 (>= 2.0.11), libpci3 (>= 1:3.8.0), libperl5.34 (>= 5.34.0), libpython3.10 (>= 3.10.0), libslang2 (>= 2.2.4), libssl3 (>= 3.0.0), libunwind8, zlib1g (>= 1:1.2.3.3), libelf-dev, gcc
    Filename: pool/main/l/linux-liquorix/linux-headers-6.2.5-4-liquorix-amd64_6.2-4ubuntu1~kinetic_amd64.deb
    Size: 13024720
    MD5sum: 408eed69501fbb2dc1a2353ef9da15e9
    SHA1: e2529688a461b90fddfdc835c721ec3d95868033
    SHA256: e52c16079c27778e7f7b250cdf67fa6b7a5d47dc6e646eca838e5fefec9bcae4
    Description: Header files for Linux 6.2.5-4-liquorix-amd64
    Description-md5: 7eede16ef495010bf8296c1ea7b455fa
```

Comment: Run `apt update` first.

Comment: yes of course I do that.

Comment: I found a workaround, is that the same a solution? The workaround doesn't explain what the problem is or why it happened.

Answer (score 1):

This is a workaround rather than an answer, since it does not explain the cause of the problem.

I removed and re-added the PPA. This fixed the problem on both machines.